# why not db_query? (drupal db layer)

Tags: database, drupal

The drupal database layer api says about db_query

> Do not use this function for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE queries. Those should be handled via db_insert(), db_update() and db_delete() respectively.
>   [(source)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7)

I think this is said for other database layers as well. Does anybody know why? Is it unsafe, inefficient, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just convention as far as I know. Certainly there's no technical problem with running an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` through `db_query()`; all it does is run a vanilla SQL query against the database so it will definitely work.

I'd imagine the documentation is simply pointing out that there are dedicated functions for those operations, and that those should be preferred to running an SQL `INSERT` etc. directly.

'Structured' queries (i.e. those using `db_select()`, `db_insert()`, `db_update()` and `db_merge()`) will also get the added benefit of being run through [`hook_query_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7) before they're executed, meaning other parts of the system can alter them as required. You don't get that same functionality when using `db_query()`.